# Batch Execution of AWS Step-Function State Machines

Tags: c#, aws-step-functions

I'm somewhat of an AWS noob, and have just started working with Lambda task-based step functions and state machines. I created a multi-step state machine that passes a a request object from step to step and acts on it. What I don't understand is how I would execute the state machine for a large number requests. Would I simply call "start execution" for every request, even if there are 1000s, or is there a more efficient way to handle it? Any thoughts on approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run multiple state machines at the same time, but keep in mind the service limits for both [Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits.html) and your [Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) tasks.

Based on the limits for open executions (1,000,000 at the time of writing this), the service is built to handle thousands at a time.